# Interview - 7 ways to store and compare millions of data

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bigdata

Was just asked this day before.

```
Could come up with - 
1. Arrays
2. Linked Lists
3. Sets/Vectors
4. Min/Max heaps
5. Trees
6. Map
```

Interviewer said I haven't included one obvious answer which is as good, if not better than trees (assuming, they are balanced). Any ideas?

Comment: How about `Map`?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include Map. I had given Map as an answer as well.

Comment: @user10141156 Did you not ask the interviewer after the interview?

Comment: @user10141156 `compare millions of data`- what kind of comparison?

Comment: @vivek_23 I did. He said, find out about it - "It'll be a nice exercise", he said.

Comment: @vivek_23 that wasn't important to him. When asked, he said - just assume it's sorting the entire bunch of numbers.

Comment: Maybe, hash tables?

Comment: @user10141156 `It'll be a nice exercise` Huh! this works only if you were selected and could meet him/her again to figure out what he/she needed. Otherwise, he/she needs to answer it right away. Other ways remaining as far as I see can be `stacks` and `queues`.

Comment: Database is a good one. Skip list is as good or better than binary tree in many cases.

Comment: Since you seem to cover most of the fundamental data structures in your answer, then one possible choice that you might have missed could be graphs. I think an algorithm using a graph to sort millions of numbers would be neither practical nor obvious. The formation of edges would be too expensive, much like the cost of using linked lists. However, since your interviewer didn't care much about the type of comparison involved in processing this data, there may be a case to be made for the usefulness of graphs in topological sorting.

Comment: A tree or hash table (or array, linked-list or whatever else, if you really want) can be a map or a set, so map and set probably aren't descriptive enough by themselves (similarly for stack and queue). A vector is usually an array (at least in C++ it is).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of options that can be added. Skip list, graph, btree, log-structured merge-tree, bloom filter...

I consider that a horrible interview question.  The interviewer is asking for useless trivia, and believes that how much trivia you know in common with the interviewer is a measure of something useful.  Speaking personally, I'd consider that a red flag that would limit my interest in the company.